# Manually setting seed for random sorting with SphinxSE?

Tags: mysql, random, sphinx

I need to do a Sphinx query with pseudo-random sorting. To be able to get repeatable results, I'd like to be able to provide a seed that I define to the random function. But I can't seem to find any documentation for doing this with SphinxSE (the MySQL engine). I found in the docs that you can do this using SphinxQL via `OPTION rand_seed`. What would be the equivalent in SphinxSE? So far I could only figure out `sort=extended:@random;` which gets automatically seeded.

Answer (score 0):

In SphinxAPI there is 'hack' to put options via setSelect with a 'comment'...

```
 $cl->setSelect("* /* OPTION rand_seed=123 */");
```

I dont know, but its POSSIBLE it might work via SphinxSE ?

```
WHERE query = 'test;sort=extended:@random;select=* /* OPTION rand_seed=123 */'
```

(I dont have a an active SphinxSE installation to test)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried running that query but it doesn't seem like the OPTION is being processed. I've also tried to set max_matches=1 and it did not return just one match. For now I'm using an expression to generate a somewhat "random" order based on a seed and the ID of each match, via sort=expr:f(seed, id). Maybe I should just switch to SphinxQL since it seems that offers the most flexibility...